# How do I know if someone has installed screen sharing on my Mac?

Tags: screen-sharing

I think someone might have installed screen sharing on another account on my computer, but I would like to know if my screen is being shared. How would I know?

Comment: you are not giving us the whole picture here. so someone (you know) is sharing the Mac with you. They have they own account but have no access to your account ? So now you want to know if they can see your data via screen sharing.

Comment: Alternatively - is this a managed machine, owned by a business or school? Screen-sharing is already built-into the OS.. but it needs authority to be able to log in using it.

Comment: Please be more specific, especially if you are worried about the built-in screen sharing feature or a 3rd party app. The analysis required and the potential answers differ greatly formthese cases.

Answer (score 0):

A bare minium you could do is would be if you just look up if the Screen Sharing is enabled in System Preference > Sharing

[image]

Unfortunately there are other ways to do screen sharing without using above.

Comment: Screen sharing enabled ≠ screen is being shared.